How to install and use bayesnf package in windows with CPU
I want to use a python package association with this GitHub page. I installed it on my system (As suggested in the Github page using Python 3.10 version and on a new environment) which is Windows 10 and I only have CPU (I don't have GPU).
When I ran:
import bayesnf

I got the following error which is related to JAX:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 import bayesnf

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\bayesnf\__init__.py:21
     17 # A new PyPI release will be pushed every time __version__ is increased.
     18 # When changing this, also update the CHANGELOG.md
     19 __version__ = '0.1.3'
---> 21 from .spatiotemporal import BayesianNeuralFieldMAP
     22 from .spatiotemporal import BayesianNeuralFieldMLE
     23 from .spatiotemporal import BayesianNeuralFieldVI

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\bayesnf\spatiotemporal.py:19
     15 """API for Bayesian Neural Field estimators."""
     17 from collections.abc import Sequence
---> 19 import jax
     20 import jax.numpy as jnp
     21 import numpy as np

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\jax\__init__.py:25
     22 from jax.version import __version_info__ as __version_info__
     24 # Set Cloud TPU env vars if necessary before transitively loading C++ backend
---> 25 from jax._src.cloud_tpu_init import cloud_tpu_init as _cloud_tpu_init
     26 try:
     27   _cloud_tpu_init()

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\cloud_tpu_init.py:17
     15 import os
     16 from jax import version
---> 17 from jax._src import config
     18 from jax._src import hardware_utils
     20 running_in_cloud_tpu_vm: bool = False

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\config.py:27
     24 import threading
     25 from typing import Any, Generic, NamedTuple, NoReturn, Protocol, TypeVar, cast
---> 27 from jax._src import lib
     28 from jax._src.lib import jax_jit
     29 from jax._src.lib import transfer_guard_lib

File ~\pyenv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\lib\__init__.py:76
     71   return _jaxlib_version
     74 version_str = jaxlib.version.__version__
     75 version = check_jaxlib_version(
---> 76   jax_version=jax.version.__version__,
     77   jaxlib_version=jaxlib.version.__version__,
     78   minimum_jaxlib_version=jax.version._minimum_jaxlib_version)
     80 # Before importing any C compiled modules from jaxlib, first import the CPU
     81 # feature guard module to verify that jaxlib was compiled in a way that only
     82 # uses instructions that are present on this machine.
     83 import jaxlib.cpu_feature_guard as cpu_feature_guard

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)

Given that I have windows 10 and I use CPU only, I'm wondering if it is possible to use this package on my system. Otherwise, I would be appreciated if you help suggest a solution for using it.
The GitHub page says:

The system is build on the JAX machine learning platform.


The typical install time is 1 minute. This software is tested on Python 3.10 with a standard Debian GNU/Linux setup. The large-scale experiments in scripts/ were run using TPU v3-8 accelerators. To run BayesNF locally on medium to large-scale data, a GPU is required at minimum.


What is the name of your Python script? jax.py?

This error:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)

typically means that you've installed incompatible jax and jaxlib packages. You can figure out which versions you have installed by running this:
python -m pip list | grep jax

You can install updated JAX and jaxlib versions for CPU by running this:
python -m pip install -U jax

At that point the import should no longer lead to this attribute error.
